# ras pi 4 has terrible video rendering performance when streaming in vnc and firefox.Do i need to install specific drivers

Tags: pi-4, gpu

I cant understand why either my raspberry pi 3 or my pi 4 wont adequately stream video from youtube . It is unbearbly choppy and  sluggish.

Comment: What happens if you plug a screen into the Pi4 and don’t use VNC?